# I want to create a dummy file in specific path of unix server but I want to create it through powershell scripting

Tags: unix, powershell-3.0

Eg : gpfs/code/text/dummy.txt - this is my unix path.
Dummy.txt is a dummy file.
How to create this dummy file in unix path through powershell scripting.

Can you please provide me the code as I am new in powershell

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this sample command:

```
echo $null >> filename
```

Also you can use `copy` command:

```
copy NUL: filename
```

Comment: Romeo ninov , Thanks for reply. Can u please tell me how will I connect powershell to unix

Comment: Please create new question. And clarify why you need powershell when you have `ksh`,`sh`, `bash`, `csh` and so on!